# How to iterate over "this" keyword in c# and Blazor

Tags: c#, razor, blazor, this

I currently am trying to dynamically get all variables for a given page using the "this" keyword and convert it to a JSON format. I can see that the "this" keyword contains all the information I am looking for but when trying to convert using `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this)` it returns an empty string.

I have gone about the route of possibly doing a foreach on the "this" value but get an error that the page's class doesn't contain a definition for `GetEnumerator`. I'm looking for a way to either iterate over "this" by typecasting it to an `IEnumerable` or correctly implement the `GetEnumerator` definition to be able to iterate over the object itself. My ultimate goal is to get something like

```
string jsonData= "";

foreach (var item in this)
{
    jsonData += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
}
```

or even better just string

```
jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
```

A more proper example may be within a file "Pages/Index" having

```
@page "/home"
<h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>
@code{
int tester = 13;
NavigationManager navMan = new NavigationManager();
UserService user = new UserService();
}
```

Theoretically I could do

```
string jsonData = "";
jsonData += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.user);
jsonData += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.navMan);
...
```

which would work correctly but would be very time consuming given some pages contain hundreds of variables.

By running the server in debugger I can see within "this" it contains something such as

```
navMan | Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Server.Circuits.RemoteNavigationManager
user | Services.UserService
tester | 13
```

Which in itself by expanding one like "user" I can see it contains for values for name, email, etc.

By doing `jsonData += JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.user);`, I get back the name, email, etc. variable names and values saves into `jsonData` but would like to do this for each of the objects within "this" without having to hardcode each variable into the `SerializeObject` function

Comment: What *object* does `this` refer to?  If that object is not iterable, why are you trying to iterate over it?  What is the goal of that?  What resulting JSON are you expecting to convert that object into?

Comment: @David this is an object of type .razor as it is a custom razor component class. While running the webserver in debugger, I can see that "this" contains in my case 6 different object types that I'd like to convert to JSON. For example, one of the objects within "this" is my NavigationManager service. By simply doing JsonConvert.SerializeObject(NavigationManager); I get the relevant JSON information I am looking for such as the URI but I'd like to do this process for all the objects contained within "this"

Comment: If the data you want is in properties on the object then you should be able to serialize that object.  But without a [mcve] all anybody can do is guess about that object.  If you're able to access one of the values you want to serialize and successfully serialize it, then you should be able to do that for all of the values you want.  How dynamic does this operation need to be?  Do you know in advance the values you want to serialize?  If not then you can use reflection to "iterate" an object's properties/fields/etc.  But that sounds like overkill here.

Comment: @David see edit

Comment: And if you do `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` what happens?

Comment: jsonData = {} @DimitrisMaragkos

Comment: [Polite] What's the point in serializing a component instance?  You can't de-serialize it and use it because that's not the way the UI works.  Same goes for a service object.  You can't de-serialize an instance of `NavigationManager` and use it.

Comment: I wont need to de-serialize it, just need to save the json within a database @MrCakaShaunCurtis

Comment: I would guess that many of the objects aren't serializable (I've never tried it).   In which case your down to Reflection and figuring out how to save objects like `RenderFragment` and `RenderHandle`.  If you want to save the state of the objects for some reason, setup an interface with a `WriteToJson` method and then implement it in any objects you want to generate the state (and write only the information you want to preserve).  Much of what's in `ComponentBase` will be gobbledegook.  You could even create a custom attribute to identify the fields and then have a boilerplate `WriteToJson`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);` returns empty json is because by default Newtonsoft.Json serializes only public members. So I enabled serialization of all members by adding.

```
@attribute [JsonObjectAttribute(MemberSerialization = MemberSerialization.Fields)]
```

Then I got exception 'Self referencing loop detected...' so to fix that I added.

```
string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this, new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ReferenceLoopHandling = ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore
});
```

After that I got exception 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'. So at that point I stopped because it looks like trying to serialize the whole razor component is a bad idea.

So instead of all this nonsense I suggest to simply manually add `[JsonProperty]` to the members that you want to get serialized and hope for the best:

```
@page "/home"

<h2>HELLO WORLD</h2>

@code {
    [JsonProperty]
    int tester = 13;

    [JsonProperty]
    [Inject]
    NavigationManager navMan { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty]
    UserService user = new UserService();

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        string jsonData = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: What if NavigationManager and UserService are injected rather than declared within the razor component?

Comment: Instead of injecting using systax `@inject NavigationManager NavMan`, declare it as property inside `@code { }` and add `[Inject]` attribute: `[JsonProperty] [Inject] NavigationManager NavMan { get; set; }`